# How to Get started to build UI of website

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I developed a system with no styling (no bootstrap and CSS) now i need to add them. i do not have a proper knowledge about bootstrap but went through W3Schools and understood the concepts. Now my problem is I can not understand the sequence of implementation i.e what must be done first then second then third etc. and how to use the concepts. It would be grateful if someone could please provide me some help in sorting out my issues. Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the stylesheets / js / etc. to your `<head>` section in your html like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

From here on, you're ready to go.

See [this as an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/zL0r5t4n/)

Comment: thanks. do i also need to specify the grid in the start

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve. But using the bootstrap grid-layout is always a good way to start. See [this guide](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) on how to use it.

Comment: is it advisable to use a template or code everything....just to know that my friend said that it would take a long time to code is it true

Comment: You can always use a template, but for learning how everything works within bootstrap, you should go for doing it yourself. Also, how long it takes depends on how big your website is.